# Three.js alpha tearing

Tags: three.js, alpha

I am currently playing around with ThreeJs ( Canvas mode ) and Im having an alpha issue.

I am trying to get a solid sphere rotating anti clockwise around Y,  with a slightly bigger semi transparent sphere rotating clockwise around it. When they are stationary and I move the camera everything seems fine but as soon as I add the rotation the semi transparent sphere "tears" or clips with the smaller solid sphere.

I have had a look around StackOverflow for a solution and have made sure everything has a y > 0, renderer.sortObjects is false and transparents are set to true and had a play around with depthWrite/depthTest and I cant seem to change the result.

If I make the inner sphere a lot smaller it seems to fix the problem but for the task in hand I need to have the 2 spheres at near the same size.

I have also had a play around with the near and far plane clips as I thought it might be related to a z-depth resolution but that made no difference.

Here's a jsFiddle of the problem,  any help will be much appreciated.

```
enter code here
var container;
var camera;
var scene;
var renderer;
var objects = [];

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    var info = document.createElement('div');
    info.style.position = 'absolute';
    info.style.top = '10px';
    info.style.width = '100%';
    info.style.textAlign = 'center';
    container.appendChild(info);

    var width = window.innerWidth
    var height = window.innerHeight

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height , 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 10, 400);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // object 1
    var geometryOne = new THREE.SphereGeometry(190, 10, 10);
    var materialOne = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff,
        opacity: 1.0,
        transparent: true
    });

    var objectOne = new THREE.Mesh(geometryOne, materialOne);

    objectOne.position.x = 0.0;
    objectOne.position.y = 10.0;
    objectOne.position.z = 0.0;

    objectOne.scale.x = 1.0;
    objectOne.scale.y = 1.0;
    objectOne.scale.z = 1.0;

    objectOne.rotation.x = 0.0;
    objectOne.rotation.y = 0.0;
    objectOne.rotation.z = 0.0;

    scene.add(objectOne);
    objects.push(objectOne);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // object 2
    var geometryTwo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 10, 10);
    var materialTwo = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffff00,
        opacity: 0.5,
        transparent: true,
        depthWrite: false,
        depthTest: false
    });

    var objectTwo = new THREE.Mesh(geometryTwo, materialTwo);

    objectTwo.position.x = 0.0;
    objectTwo.position.y = 10.0;
    objectTwo.position.z = 10.0;

    objectTwo.scale.x = 1.0;
    objectTwo.scale.y = 1.0;
    objectTwo.scale.z = 1.0;

    objectTwo.rotation.x = 0.0;
    objectTwo.rotation.y = 0.0;
    objectTwo.rotation.z = 0.0;

    scene.add(objectTwo);
    objects.push(objectTwo);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //renderer
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.sortObjects = false;

    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //event listener(s)
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    objects[0].rotation.y += 0.001;
    objects[1].rotation.y -= 0.001;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tonka_thompson/qwjWG/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `CanvasRenderer`, you can reduce artifacts by increasing the tessellation (number of facees) of your geometry:

```
var geometryOne = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 24, 16 );
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwjWG/3/

three.js r.59

Comment: Ok,  excellent,  thanks.  I thought I might have been missing a material setting or something but this is a perfect fix thanks.